# issues running jiraSOAP from ruby

Tags: soap, jira, ruby-1.9.2

I am trying my hands on accessing jira from ruby using the jiraSOAP gem.
I'm running ruby 1.9.2

But the moment I pass in my login credentials, I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: The response is not a valid SOAP envelope`
`from /Users/rahulbaxi/.rvm/gems/ruby1.9.2p180/gems/handsoap1.1.8/lib/handsoap-/service.rb:388:in on_missing_document'`

```
from /Users/rahulbaxi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/handsoap-1.1.8/lib/handsoap/service.rb:442:in `parse_http_response'`
from /Users/rahulbaxi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/handsoap-1.1.8/lib/handsoap/service.rb:250:in `invoke'
from /Users/rahulbaxi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/jiraSOAP-0.10.3/lib/jiraSOAP/api.rb:55:in `build'
from /Users/rahulbaxi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/jiraSOAP-0.10.3/lib/jiraSOAP/api.rb:69:in `soap_call'
from /Users/rahulbaxi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/jiraSOAP-0.10.3/lib/jiraSOAP/api.rb:18:in `login'
from (irb):3
from /Users/rahulbaxi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'`
```

Please help me out fix this!

Comment: Can you offer any code or an example of the XML that is being sent to the JIRA?

Comment: i get this as soon as i try to connect using my login credentials:
these are the steps i followed:
ran some code in irb:
`require 'jirasoap'`

`jira = Jira::JiraService.new "<location to my jira repo>"`

`jira.login = <login credentials>`

and boom the moment i hit enter, i get the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using [jira4r-jh](https://github.com/rb512/jira4r-jh) which works just fine with ruby 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of these samples will help.

http://jira4r.rubyhaus.org/2+minute+walkthrough
http://blogs.reucon.com/srt/2007/11/05/accessing_jira_from_ruby.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'jira4r/jira4r'

jira = Jira::JiraTool.new(2, "http://jira.atlassian.com")
jira.login("soaptester", "soaptester")

puts jira.getProject("DEMO").inspect
```

Comment: Do you have any documentation for this JIRA SOAP gem?

Comment: yep, it can be found here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/jiraSOAP/0.10.3/frames

i followed the "Getting Started" guide in here, but it didn't help me much..

Comment: Thanks for helping out Jason!  I've dropped the idea of using jiraSOAP.

Comment: Do you mean that particular jiraSOAP gem or the JIRA SOAP API in general? I hope the later is not the case, because it really is a powerful and effective tool for remote JIRA access. Also, it may not be out of the question to use the SOAP API (or REST API) manually. When I needed remote JIRA access for a ColdFusion project there was not a library available, so I simply built the API myself implementing only the features that I needed as I needed them.

Comment: nah! i meant jiraSOAP, the gem.  I'm using jira4r now. However, it's got lesser exposure to the jira's soap library than jiraSOAP, but I found a workaround.  I too feel the need of building an API myself now!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you ensure that the JIRA instance has the RPC feature turned on?

It would be *really* helpful to see the HTTP response that is coming from the JIRA server and to know what version of JIRA it is

Comment: yes, it's turned on.  (i am able to query jira from jira4r and ruby 1.8.7)
and the jira version am using is 4.2.2
i suppose i'll have to make my own webservice call if i've to see the HTTP response, right?

Comment: You can put a proxy in between your Ruby app and the service. This is usually pretty easy. Some good proxy's are Charles and WebScarab.